# Item allocation algorithm with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I'm working on a kind of resource allocation problem in Spark.

Suppose there is a list of people and an item that they want from a list of pre-selected items.

For example :

List of pre-selected items are I1, I2, I3

Another list is people's wish list :

```
P1 want I1

P2 wants I1

P3 wanta I2

P4 wants I3
```

And the list goes on for billion of rows.

Now since there is a limited inventory for each item the user want the only solution I can imagine is sequential.

If I want to go parallel with Spark I can't find any data structure/type that can be used to have a shared, strongly consistent state where I can decrement the inventory after one item has been allocated.

I looked into Apache Ignite but I couldn't find a way to use it within same job but with all the executors.

Is there some shared cache thing in Spark that I'm unaware of ?

Or is there some other framework with the speed and resiliency of Spark that I can leverage here ?

Comment: for me it's unclear what you try to achieve. Is this something like more people have the same item in the shopping cart then the item is available?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Yes.. the problem is more number of people have an item in there list than its actually available in inventory. Hence I need some kind of allocation done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want share spark data, you can use Apache Ignite. It has integration with spark - IgniteRDD, which will help you to store all data in cache and then access it from different places.

Entry point for this integration: https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html

Documentation: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v2.1/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd

Comment: Can IgniteRDD help me in sharing data within different executors of same Spark Job ?

Comment: There is a simple Ignite cache under IgniteRDD, so I don't see any problems here

Comment: Can IgniteRDD be updated concurrently and updates are seen by every executors ?

Comment: Have you checked the link I've provided? https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignite-for-spark 
Just read documentation, it mention everything you need

Comment: Yes I did take a look at it. But the example shows one job creating the IgniteRDD making changes to it and then the other job can read the state where First job left. My question now is that I wan''t to maintain some shared state which will be updated and read concurrently by different executors. Does IgniteRDD suite such use case ?

Comment: Also will it be a good idea to use an IgniteRDD as a shared counter for all the executors ?